# How to get formulas of multiple regressions by vectorizing

Tags: r, vectorization, lm

Suppose I have the following code that makes multiple regressions and stores the lm and lm with stepwise selection models in tibbles:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(MASS)
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(A = sample(3, 10, replace = T), 
                 B = sample(100, 10, replace = T), 
                 C = sample(100, 10, replace = T))
df <- df %>% arrange(A)

formula_df <- as.tibble(NA)
aic_df <- as.tibble(NA)

for (i in unique(df$A)){
    temp <- df %>% filter(A == i)

    formula_df[i, 1] <- temp %>% 
        do(model = lm(B ~ C, data = .))

    aic_df[i, 1] <- temp %>%
        do(model = stepAIC(formula_df[[1,1]], direction = "both", trace = F))
}
```

Is it possible to vectorize to make it faster, for example using the *pply functions? The loop becomes extremely slow when the data gets larger. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
model <- df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
    summarise(formula_model = list(lm(B ~ C))) %>% 
    mutate(aic_model = list(stepAIC(.[[1,2]], direction = "both", trace = F)))
```

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thanks!